# Error occurred when accessing to Office 365 calendar via EWS API

Tags: api, exchangewebservices

My partner started to experience the error message when accessing the Office 365 calendar data via EWS API, and for some Office 365 tenant end-users get an error message below:

---

### The specified object was not found in the store., Can't connect to the mailbox of user Mailbox database guid: 41a840ac-87c3-4a8b-93d8-e334353bd51d because the ExchangePrincipal object contains outdated information. The mailbox may have been moved recently.

The error does not occurr in accessing via OWA or Outlook but EWS API. It used be working fine, but the problem started to occurre on some Office 365 tenant not all tenants. The similar issue was discussed in the community site bwlow, but we could not get to the information to resolve the error.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10-mso_2016/connect-to-outlook-over-ews-or-eas-not-working/38513de8-56ff-4eec-ba36-26fa2da890d5?auth=1

## Question to Ask;

Is there any information in what scenario or situation (e.g. modifying use ids or else) potentially cause this error message? Any information to fix the error?

Thank you, Tomonori

Comment: Are the tenants using Hybrid ? is a service account being used ? are they using the X-AnchorMalbox Header . Have you check the Guid that its is in the error eg does it belong to the Mailbox being accessed

Comment: Thanks for the comments! It is not a hybrit scenario, and our partner is ISV with providing their own calendar service with using EWS API to fetch calendar data from Office365 and to display in their services. No error ocurred in OWA or outllook access, but the error occurred in EWS API access. This type of issue can be investigated by MS in premier support, but they has no premier contract yet and they are desperate how to investigate/resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When creating exchange service try it with different versions,  We're currently migrating to 365 but **ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1** worked instead of 2013 (depends on what version you migrating from)

ExchangeService exchangeService = new ExchangeService(**ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1**)

this fixed below issue:
*The specified object was not found in the store., Can't connect to the mailbox of user Mailbox database guid: ###### because the ExchangePrincipal object contains outdated information. The mailbox may have been moved recently.*

Comment: I have tried changing the `ExchangeVersion` as suggested. It did not change the error message. There is a discussion of this issue [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ee6e943f-e103-4abf-957f-19a42aa8a91b/ews-with-o365-has-been-broken-for-the-past-24-hours-for-us) which suggests that it is to do with an ongoing (early Sept. 2018) Microsoft data move related to GDPR legislation. (Obviously even if that suggestion is right then given the date of the OP question here, this cannot be the only possible source of the issue, but maybe one possible source.)

Comment: We're having the same issue still

Comment: different version worked for different mailboxes but once I found the working version for each resource then it was smooth and I migrated lots of rooms each with tons of meetings.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `X-AnchorMailbox` header with the email address solved this issue for us:

`X-AnchorMailbox: example@mailbox.com`

More info: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdav_101/2018/06/16/best-practices-important-and-critical-headers-for-ews/